# Why does the RadioButton's Click events fire before CheckedChanged?

Tags: .net, events, textbox, radio-button

In my .NET application's GUI (done in C#, but I don't think that matters) are `TextBox`es and `RadioButton`s handling user changeable data.

For the TextBoxes, I handle the `KeyDown` and the `TextChanged` event. During the initial setting of the TextBoxes' `Text`, of course the `TextChanged` event fires, but since there was no `KeyDown` event first, the data is not changed by the user (so it does not have to be written back to the store).

Now I wanted to use the same technique for the RadioButtons using the `Click` or `MouseClick` event as a user interaction detector. Unfortunately both `Click` events fire *after* the `CheckedChanged` event.

This - IMHO - is just wrong. The `Checked` property cannot change *before* the control is clicked. Is this a logical error or does this happen for a reason? Is there any way to force correct behaviour?

(To solve the GUI problem, of course I could monitor the more fitting equivalent `MouseDown` or just introduce a variable for initial setting of the Control's values. But this is about understanding the logic here.)

Comment: Just for clarification, when the form loads, is the focus is set to the first  textbox? Why should the `TextChanged` event fire? Also, do you set your RadioButton's `CHECKED` state = False? When a radio button is checked/unchecked, does your data (stored in SQL/Access/etc?) automatically update?

Comment: This is not about form loading or focus. This is about changing properties either programmatically or by user input. If I set the `Text` property programmatically, of course the `TextChanged` event fires. If the user enters data, the `KeyDown` event fires _before_ that. For the Radio, if I set `Checked` programmatcially, `CheckedChange`fires, as it does if the user clicks the Radio. The thing is: the `Click` and `MouseClick` event fire _after_ the `CheckedChange` event. And I wonder why.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is bizarre and definitely wrong. I don't have a real resolution for you except that I've had issues with event firing before. It sounds stupid, but make sure your code has the programatic event first and then the user event. If that isn't the case or doesn't help, I would suggest recreating the form (or whatever object these controls are found). I have had problems with corrupted forms that make events fire incorrectly. Recreating the form from scratch was really annoying but it worked. Let me know if you find a solution.